# where is skb_push for udp header in kernel?

Tags: linux, udp, kernel

I have been looking for the udp packet sending issue for a whole afternoon. It is said sendmsg system call would first comes to the inet_sendmsg, and then udp_sendmsg, then udp_push_pending_frames, in this function, UDP header is filled in before ip_push_pending_frames. However, according to http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb_data.html, UDP layer should have a pure user data as data in skb, and it skb_push to get room for UDP header. I just couldn't find it.

Anyone can offer some clue?

Thanks!

Comment: Emm. I think the udp layer doesn't call similar function of skb_push to allocate memory for UDP header, because the udp_hdr function, which is skb_transport_header, it has skb->head + skb->transport_header, this is the offset in the head room, so I guess only IP has the duty to push headers into data. Not check yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find `skb_push` in `include/linux/skbuff.h` in the kernel source - it's an inline function so it is in a header file rather than a normal source file.

Comment: Hi, I know where it is defined, but I don't know where it is called by udp layer in order to insert the UDP header. According to that link, udp should see a pure user data in skb->data, and it calls skb_push somewhere to insert its header. I cannot find this "somewhere"